# Should we get a blog?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog, site-promotion

We have now [got a blog](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/223). Please volunteer and post any suggestions on the new post; this post won't be checked regularly. The original text is kept below for completeness.

---

Blogs are very interesting things. They let us share content that doesn't fit with the question / answer format, and collect information that would otherwise be scattered around the internet.

If we get a blog, we need people to put stuff in it. So, if you want the blog and want to put content on it, please show your commitment.

Comment: If anybody wants to commit to the blog, or has any ideas, please post a comment or answer to this question.

Comment: What sort of content would be suitable for the blog?  I'm not sure I'm clear on its purpose.

Comment: @mnem Things that fit our site's description but wouldn't work with the Q&A format.

Comment: @mnem I suggest looking at some of the [interesting content on the SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) for inspiration.

Comment: Note that new Blog Overflow powered blogs [aren't being done](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30554990#30554990) anymore

Comment: @Quill Yes, we're trying to work out a domain. On the one hand, we want something cheap, but on the other we want full access to the latest WordPress (or whatever engine we end up using) so we don't have to trust people to share accounts on it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I suggest using Medium, or similar. Maybe try speaking to the guys from Worldbuilding, they run an offsite blog

Answer (score 8):

I could contribute with some interesting stories about how I have been developing [software for MSX computers](https://bitbucket.org/konamiman/msx/src) during the last 25 years, how I presented [a TCP/IP stack written in Z80 assembler](http://www.konamiman.com/msx/msx-e.html#inl2) as my final thesis in the university, how I wrote [a Z80 simulator in C#](https://bitbucket.org/konamiman/z80dotnet) just for fun (and then [a MSX emulator](https://bitbucket.org/konamiman/nestormsx) as a proof of concept), and how all of this helped me to some degree in being hired at Stack Overflow. So yes, upvote for this. :-)

Comment: The blog is ready. Please set your site email address (in your preferences) to the address you wish to use for the blog, then reply to this comment.

Comment: I've invited you now. Follow the instructions in the email then you're good to go! :-) Please wait until the formal [meta-tag:status-completed] before making any posts public though.

Comment: Blog status: [completed](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/223/).

Answer (score 6):

I'd be willing to contribute some.  My retro experience is mostly with the Tandy / Radio Shack line of computers, Apple IIe's, and Atari 2600 gaming consoles.  I do have some experience writing articles/posts (mostly about Cassandra and the NoSQL world), but I'd be happy to help out.

Comment: Thank you for volunteering. We will be happy to accept your articles on the blog.

Comment: The blog is ready. Please set your site email address (in your preferences) to the address you wish to use for the blog, then reply to this comment.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Email appears to be set, so I should be ready to go!

Comment: I've invited you now. Follow the instructions in the email then you're good to go! :-) Please wait until the formal [meta-tag:status-complete] (shouldn't be long!) before making any posts public though.

Comment: Blog status: [completed](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/223/).

Answer (score 5):

If you're still looking for people to contribute, I could write some blog posts.

I couldn't think of anything to write about at first. As someone too young to have firsthand experience, I don't feel like I'm really an expert in anything "Retrocomputing". <sub><sup>I hope I'm not making anyone feel old. :)</sup></sub>

But after some point in time, there will be nobody left that experienced these things firsthand.

One of the things that I could write about is my search for information on COMIT. It's one of those languages that might as well have ceased to exist at some point a while ago, but pieces still remain to be put back together (as hard as it is to find anything).

I think that it's important that we try to ensure our site is as welcoming as possible to anyone wanting to learn about retrocomptuing, and I hope that I'll be able to write in a way that shows that it's not necessary to have experience to participate on our site.

Comment: The blog is ready. Please set your site email address (in your preferences) to the address you wish to use for the blog, then reply to this comment.

Comment: If you want to be in on the blog when it launches, please follow the above instructions. Otherwise we'll have to start without you.

Comment: Last call before we launch the blog. Please follow the above instructions or you won't be able to publish on the blog at its launch.

Comment: The blog is now [live](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/223/). You can still write stuff though; just follow the above instructions then reply to this comment.

Answer (score 4):

I'm happy to do a few posts! Probably mostly on the Atari front though I've picked up some older Macs and a Pentium PC recently.

Comment: The blog is ready. Please reply to my comment on RetroMods with the email address you wish to use for the blog.

Comment: You've been invited. This comment only exists to help me keep track of who's been invited and who hasn't.

Comment: Blog status: [completed](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/223/).

Answer (score 4):

I could post about old Apple machines such as the Apple Lisa and the II.

Comment: You're a new user, but your contributions so far are good (better than most of my first posts!) so you can participate in the blog.  Please set your site email address (in your preferences) to the address you wish to use for the blog, then reply to this comment.

Comment: I've invited you now. Follow the instructions in the email then you're good to go! :-) Please wait until the formal [meta-tag:status-completed] before making any posts public though. (You can create and save drafts so long as you don't press Publish.)

Comment: Blog status: [completed](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/223/).