# Should we allow questions about where to buy parts?

Tags: discussion, scope, shopping-questions

This question
[Where can I find an external 8-inch floppy disk drive?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/756/where-can-i-find-an-external-8-inch-floppy-disk-drive)

Raised a couple of issues for me while I think it's just about on topic (given the age of hardware and difficulty) it does leave me wondering what the correct response to questions like:

> Where can I buy a replacement Apple II PSU in Europe?

While it's on topic is a list of vendors (which I assume would be the answer) a good stackexchange answer.

Another similar question is ["Where to buy a 6502 chip"](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15100/7208).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, any question related to where one might buy equipment or software (retro or otherwise) or asking for buying recommendations are usually off-topic across *all* SE sites. As stated in other answers, the answers for such questions will get stale fast, and will need constant grooming. Not to mention that list-type answers will have to be organized into general- and system- specific sections.

No one really wants to maintain such a FAQ-style document, and SE doesn't really want us to.

**That being said**, Retro is a bit different, in that *where* to find things is invariably part of the hobby.

We might want to check how [Amateur Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) handles these, as digging around for old equipment is a shared love between us. I suspect the answer will be "your local meetups and clubs can point you at online vendors and swap-meets" but I am happy to be surprised.

There is talk [on this Meta about a blog](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/133/12). This might be a good subject for someone who wanted to maintain a series of blog entries in a FAQ-style manner for finding old equipment online.

Comment: A quick browse and I couldn't find much about spares on the Amateur Radio SE they do have "shopping recommendations for specific products
" as being off topic. I do think where can I get spares questions should be called out as being off top on the help centre page.

Comment: It was just a guess. If the hams don't have a way to allow shopping to be on topic, I don't think we will either.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it would be a good question for the SE format.  The answer would invariably be a list and would require constant updating as various suppliers entered and exited the market, changed web addresses, etc.